# I am Unable to acces the map values(Highlighted line)

Tags: apex

The Highlighted line is showing error like variable does not exist

```java
global class Updating_MembershipSalesLines1 implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        Map<String,List<membership_sales_lines__c>> lineRelatedRecords = new Map<String,List<membership_sales_lines__c>>();       
        List<membership_sales_lines__c> memberShipRecords = [Select Id,Name,Payment_status__c,Ledger_entry_no__c from membership_sales_lines__c where Payment_status__c !='Paid'];

        for(membership_sales_lines__c sales : memberShipRecords) {
            String salesOrder = sales.Name;
            List<membership_sales_lines__c> accOppList = lineRelatedRecords.get(salesOrder);
                
            if(accOppList == null) {
                lineRelatedRecords.put(salesOrder,new List<membership_sales_lines__c>{sales});
            } else {
                lineRelatedRecords.get(salesOrder).add(sales);
            }
        }

        List<membership_sales_lines__c> paidStatusRecords = new List<membership_sales_lines__c>();
        paidStatusRecords = [select Id,Name,Payment_status__c,Ledger_entry_no__c from membership_sales_lines__c where Payment_status__c = 'Paid'];
                
        for(membership_sales_lines__c  obj : paidStatusRecords){
            if(lineRelatedRecords.containsKey(obj.Name)){
                **obj.Payment_status__c = lineRelatedRecords.get(obj.Name).Payment_status__c ;**
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`lineRelatedRecords.get(obj.Name)` points to a list, you need to first reference the list index like

`lineRelatedRecords.get(obj.Name)[0].Payment_Status__c`

Answer (score 1):

You map is defined as

```
Map<String, <List<Membership_Sales__Line__c>> lineRelatedRecords
```

when you access the map, given a key, the value that will be returned is a reference to the List stored in the Map

The following steps help iterate over the List stored in the Map:

1. Check if the Map contains the key
2. Get the value (the List) from the Map and assign it to a list
3. Loop through the list (perform null check if necessary)
4. process each record in the list

   ```
   if(lineRelatedRecords.containsKey(obj.Name){ 
        List<Membership_Sales_Line__c> myList = lineRelatedRecords.get(obj.Name); //extract list from map
        for(Membership_Sales_Line__c msl : myList){ // for each record in your list
            System.debug(msl.Payment_Status__c); //or do something else
        }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@MenachemShanowitz answer is the correct one, I'm offering this answer to help you write cleaner code, starting with better variable names, a cleaner way to add lists into maps, and use of SOQL for loops

```
Map<String,List<Membership_Sales_Lines__c>> unpaidMembershipSalesLinesBySalesOrderName = new Map<String,List<Membership_Sales_Lines__c>>(); 

for(Membership_Sales_Lines__c unpaidMembershipSalesLine : [SELECT Id,Name,Payment_status__c,Ledger_entry_no__c 
                                                                FROM membership_sales_lines__c 
                                                                WHERE Payment_status__c !='Paid']) {
  String salesOrderName = unpaidMembershipSalesLine.Name;
  if (!unpaidMembershipSalesLinesBySalesOrderName.containsKey(salesOrderName)) {
      unpaidMembershipSalesLinesBySalesOrderName.put(salesOrderName,new List<Membership_Sales_Line__c>());
      }
  unpaidMembershipSalesLinesBySalesOrderName.get(salesOrderName).add(unpaidMembershipSalesLine);
}
 
List<Membership_Sales_Lines__c> paidMembershipSalesLines = 
       [SELECT Id,Name,Payment_status__c,Ledger_entry_no__c 
           FROM membership_sales_lines__c 
           WHERE Payment_status__c = 'Paid'] 
for(Membership_Sales_Lines__c paidMembershipSalesLine :) {
  String salesOrderName = paidMembershipSalesLine.Name;
  if (unpaidMembershipSalesLinesBySalesOrderName.containsKey(salesOrderName)) {
    paidMembershipSalesLine.Payment_Status__c =
        unpaidMembershipSalesLinesBySalesOrderName.get(salesOrderName)[0].Payment_Status__c;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnaks cropredy,
But every time the index value will be only zero,
when we try to insert from data loader it will be problem